# Data too long for column for longtext datatype - MySqlException

Tags: mysql, toad

I am trying to insert string in `LONGTEXT` column. Length of string is 75402 and byte count is 150804 (about 147 KB)

[image: Table Structure]

Throws an exception `Data too long for column` On inserting record.

MySQL document state that LONGTEXT can contains maximum 4GB of data

Any suggestion will be welcome

**UPDATE:**

Exception occurs when characters length is greater than 65535

But 65536 is a max length of `TEXT` datatype and I am using `LONGTEXT` here.

Comment: what the full query and error?

Comment: Using stored procedure that works perfect. Issue arise in one condition as describe above 'Length of string is 75402 and byte count is 150804 (about 147 KB)'

Comment: Let's see the statement that throws the exception.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

> LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 − 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multibyte characters. **The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
>   also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
>   client/server protocol and available memory**. Each LONGTEXT value is
>   stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes
>   in the value.

---

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html

Comment: default value - 1048576 (1Mb) so the problem could be somewhere - how insert run? what full string? what data? and etc

Comment: @a_vlad, It is posibble that he is not using the default values

Comment: agree, for this reason i was ask him more information if it work from stored procedure, to store procedure - still need pass parameter (same packet)

Comment: @a_vlad, My query works fine, problem arise only when length of characters is greater than 65535

Comment: the question - about query :) sure You are agree - if it return error, something wrong, we can try guess or try to analyse :)

Comment: Have you tried inserting records instead of a tool, try it using directly on CLI of that server?